# Merging two lists of string

Tags: c++, list, c++11, merge, concatenation

Forgive me if this is an easy problem to fix, I am new to C++.

I have a class and a main method:

```
class Test 
{
public:
    static std::list<std::string> list1[];
};
std::list<std::string> Test::list1[] = { "apple", "orange", "pear" };

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> list2[] = { "banana", "mango", "pineapple" }; 
    Test::list1.merge(list2);
    std::cout << list1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to add list1 and list2 together so that they output "apple", "orange", "pear", "banana", "mango", "pineapple". However, when I try the method above I get an error like:

> no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char [24]" to "std::list>"

Thanks for any help.

Comment: remove the Test:: from the merge line

Comment: Remove the `[]`s from the end of your list declarations. They tell C++ that you want your variables to be an array of `std::list<std::string>`, which isn't what you want here.

Comment: @Meccano I disagree with you, list1 is in class Test, so you must declare with  `Test::list1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

class Test
{
public:
    static std::list<std::string> list1;
};
std::list<std::string> Test::list1 = { "apple", "orange", "pear" };

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> list2 = { "banana", "mango", "pineapple" };
    Test::list1.merge(list2);
    for(const auto& itr : Test::list1)
        std::cout << itr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

List don't use operator `[]`. If you want display list, you must use itr, something like above.